# How to generate a file from C-hexvalues?

Tags: c, hex, dump

I have a C-array that looks like this:

```
char hexc[] = {
    0x41, 0x80, 0x7a, 0x39, 0xea, 0x7e, 0x27, 0xfc, 
    0xe6, 0x45, 0x9c, 0x8b, 0xb5, 0xce, 0xa7, 0x35, 
    0x5f, 0xf2, 0x43, 0xcf, 0x89, 0xd8, 0x61, 0xec, 
    0xe7, 0xed, 0x2e, 0x34, 0x45, 0x0c, 0x32, 0xae, 
    0x71, 0x4f, 0x1c, 0xd8, 0xb5, 0x8c, 0x1e, 0xdd,
    0x5d, 0x90, 0xf3, 0xf2, 0xe7, 0xa6, 0x4f, 0xef, 
    0xec, 0x96, 0xe3, 0xca, 0x8e, 0xeb, 0x64, 0x1d, 
    0x18, 0xa9, 0x95, 0xec, 0x64, 0x02, 0xf8, 0x26, 
};
```

I knew that behind this hex-representations is a .GIF-file, what is the best way to generate from this hex-values a viewable file again? And how to add the missing GIF-header?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  See [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) and [`fwrite()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite).

Comment: Little endian. I would prefer C :).

Comment: @Cameron: endinaness should not have an issue on char values

Comment: @Oli: Yep, I misunderstood. Endianness is completely irrelevant here!

Comment: I don't believe that's a valid GIF file, there's [some magic](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html#Image) missing.

Comment: @maerics I haven't tried something, because I don't know how to solve a problem like this in general.

Comment: @BenVoigt you are right. I added it in the question.

Comment: You might find useful information at the omniscient [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) entry for GIF (Graphics Interchange Format).

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use .gif? Does the hex contain the header, LZO-compressed info, etc. or is it just pixels? Because it would be simpler to output a .bmp and then use, say, MSPaint to convert it if you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just open the file and write to it:

```
FILE *f = fopen("filename.gif", "wb");
if (!f) return; // or do something else
fwrite(hexc, 1, sizeof(hexc), f);
fclose(f);
```

Make sure to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Well no, you need to add a valid GIF header somehow, because that data doesn't have one.

Comment: @Ben Voigt OP didn't make clear that the data didn't contain a GIF header, just that it was a GIF file.

Comment: shouldn't you open the file in binary mode ?

Answer (score 0):

open the file as binary

```
ofstream outfile ("new.gif",ofstream::binary);
```

and then write your buffer

```
outfile.write (hexc, sizeof hexc);
```

Comment: You're using C++ functions and notations in a C question.

Comment: Indeed but the c++ tag was removed after my post.

Comment: Fair enough.  That I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Turbo C DOS code

```
/****************************************************************************
** This support Compuserve 256 colour GIF87a and GIF89a image up to        **
** 320x200 in size.                                                        **
****************************************************************************/

//This program requires a stack of at least 19.5K!!

#include "stdio.h"

typedef
  struct GIFHeader {
    char          Signature [7];
    unsigned int  ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight;
    unsigned char Depth, Background, Zero;
  };
  struct GIFDescriptor {
    char          Separator;
    unsigned int  ImageLeft, ImageTop, ImageWidth, ImageHeight;
    unsigned char Depth;
  };

  char far *Screen = (char far *)0xA0000000L;
  //For loading from the file
  FILE                 *GIFFile;
  unsigned int         BPointer;
  unsigned char        Buffer [257];
  //GIF data is stored in blocks of a certain size
  unsigned char        BlockSize;
  //For loading the code
  unsigned char        CodeSize;
  char                 BitsIn;
  unsigned char        Temp;
  //Coordinates
  unsigned int         X, Y, tlX, tlY, brX, brY;
  //The string table
  unsigned int         Prefix [4096];
  unsigned char        Suffix [4096];

//This sets the display to VGA 320x200 in 256 colours
void VGAScreen ()
{
  asm {
    mov ax, 0x13
    int 0x10
  }
}

//This resets the display to text mode
void TextScreen ()
{
  asm {
    mov ax, 0x3
    int 0x10
  }
}

//This sets a DAC register to a specific Red Green Blue-value
void SetDAC(unsigned char DAC, unsigned char R, unsigned char G, unsigned char B)
{
  outportb (0x3C8, DAC);
  outportb (0x3C9, R);
  outportb (0x3C9, G);
  outportb (0x3C9, B);
}

//This sets one pixel on the screen
void PutPixel (unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned char c)
{
  Screen [(y << 8) + (y << 6) + x] = c;
}

//Function to read from the buffer
unsigned char LoadByte ()
{
  //Read next block}
  if (BPointer == BlockSize) {
    fread (Buffer, BlockSize + 1, 1, GIFFile);
    BPointer = 0;
  }

  //Return byte
  return Buffer [BPointer++];
}

//Procedure to read the next code from the file
unsigned int ReadCode ()
{
  int           Counter;
  unsigned int  Code;

  Code = 0;
  //Read the code, bit by bit
  for (Counter = 0; Counter < CodeSize; Counter++) {
    //Maybe, a new byte needs to be loaded with a further 8 bits
    if (++BitsIn == 9) {
      Temp = LoadByte ();
      BitsIn = 1;
    }

    //Add the current bit to the code
    if (Temp & 1) Code += 1 << Counter;
    Temp >>= 1;
  }
  return Code;
}

//Procedure to draw a pixel
void NextPixel (unsigned int c)
{
  //Actually draw the pixel on screen
  PutPixel (X, Y, c & 255);

  //Move to next row, if necessary
  if (++X == brX) {
    X = tlX;
    Y++;
  }
}

//Local function to output a string. Returns the first character.
unsigned char OutString (unsigned int CurCode)
{
  unsigned int  OutCount;
  unsigned char OutCode [1024];

  //If it's a single character, output that
  if (CurCode < 256) {
    NextPixel (CurCode);
  } else {
    OutCount = 0;

    //Store the string, which ends up in reverse order
    do {
      OutCode [OutCount++] = Suffix [CurCode];
      CurCode = Prefix [CurCode];
    } while (CurCode > 255);

    //Add the last character
    OutCode [OutCount++] = CurCode;

    //Output all the string, in the correct order
    do {
      NextPixel (OutCode [--OutCount]);
    } while (OutCount);
  }
  //Return 1st character
  return CurCode;
}

//This actually loads the GIF
void LoadGIF (char *Filename)
{
  //For loading from the GIF file
  struct GIFHeader     Header;
  struct GIFDescriptor Descriptor;

  //Colour information
  unsigned char        BitsPerPixel,
                       NumOfColours;
  unsigned int         DAC;
  unsigned char        Palette [256][3];

  //For indexing the string table
  unsigned int         FirstFree, FreeCode;

  //All the code information
  unsigned char        InitCodeSize;
  unsigned int         Code, OldCode, MaxCode;

  //Special codes
  unsigned int         ClearCode, EOICode;

  //Check whether the GIF file exists, and open it
  GIFFile = fopen (Filename, "rb");
  if (GIFFile == 0) {
    TextScreen ();
    printf ("Could not open file %s", Filename);
    return;
  }

  //Read header
  fread (&Header, 6, 1, GIFFile);
  Header.Signature [6] = 0;
  fread (&Header.ScreenWidth, sizeof (Header) - 7, 1, GIFFile);

  //Check signature and terminator
  if ((strcmp (Header.Signature, "GIF87a")
    && strcmp (Header.Signature, "GIF89a"))
    || Header.Zero) {
    TextScreen ();
    printf ("Not a valid GIF file\n");
    return;
  }

  //Get amount of colours in image
  BitsPerPixel = 1 + (Header.Depth & 7);
  NumOfColours = (1 << BitsPerPixel) - 1;

  //Load global colour map
  fread (Palette, 3, (NumOfColours + 1), GIFFile);
  for (DAC = 0; DAC <= NumOfColours; DAC++)
    SetDAC (DAC, Palette [DAC][0] >> 2,
                 Palette [DAC][1] >> 2,
                 Palette [DAC][2] >> 2);

  //Load the image descriptor
  fread (&Descriptor, sizeof (Descriptor), 1, GIFFile);

  if (Descriptor.Separator != ',') {
    TextScreen ();
    printf ("Incorrect image descriptor.\n");
    return;
  }

  //Get image corner coordinates
  tlX = Descriptor.ImageLeft;
  tlY = Descriptor.ImageTop;
  brX = tlX + Descriptor.ImageWidth;
  brY = tlY + Descriptor.ImageHeight;

  //Some restrictions apply
  if (Descriptor.Depth & 128) {
    TextScreen ();
    printf ("Local colour maps not supported\n");
    return;
  }
  if (Descriptor.Depth & 64) {
    TextScreen ();
    printf ("Interlaced images not supported\n");
    return;
  }

  //Get initial code size
  fread (&CodeSize, 1, 1, GIFFile);

  //GIF data is stored in blocks, so it's necessary to know the size
  fread (&BlockSize, 1, 1, GIFFile);

  //Start loader
  BPointer = BlockSize;

  //Special codes used in the GIF spec
  ClearCode        = 1 << CodeSize;     //Code to reset
  EOICode          = ClearCode + 1;     //End of file

  //Initialize the string table
  FirstFree        = ClearCode + 2;     //Strings start here
  FreeCode         = FirstFree;         //Strings can be added here

  //Initial size of the code and its maximum value
  InitCodeSize     = ++CodeSize;
  MaxCode          = 1 << CodeSize;

  BitsIn = 8;

  //Start at top left of image
  X = Descriptor.ImageLeft;
  Y = Descriptor.ImageTop;

  do {
    //Read next code
    Code = ReadCode ();

    //If it's an End-Of-Information code, stop processing
         if (Code == EOICode) break;
    //If it's a clear code...
    else if (Code == ClearCode) {
      //Clear the string table
      FreeCode = FirstFree;

      //Set the code size to initial values
      CodeSize = InitCodeSize;
      MaxCode  = 1 << CodeSize;

      //The next code may be read
      Code = ReadCode ();
      OldCode = Code;

      //Set pixel
      NextPixel (Code);
    //Other codes
    } else {
      /*If the code is already in the string table, it's string is displayed,
      and the old string followed by the new string's first character is
      added to the string table.*/
      if (Code < FreeCode)
        Suffix [FreeCode] = OutString (Code);
      else {
      /*If it is not already in the string table, the old string followed by
      the old string's first character is added to the string table and
      displayed.*/
        Suffix [FreeCode] = OutString (OldCode);
        NextPixel (Suffix [FreeCode]);
      }

      //Finish adding to string table
      Prefix [FreeCode++] = OldCode;

      //If the code size needs to be adjusted, do so
      if (FreeCode >= MaxCode && CodeSize < 12) {
        CodeSize++;
        MaxCode <<= 1;
      }

      //The current code is now old
      OldCode = Code;
    }
  } while (Code != EOICode);

  //Close the GIF file
  fclose (GIFFile);
}

void main (int argcount, char *argvalue[])
{
  char FileName [80];

  //Check if a filename was passed as a parameter, otherwise ask for one
  if (argcount > 1) {
    strcpy (FileName, argvalue [1]);
  } else {
    printf ("Enter filename:");
    gets (FileName);
  }

  //Switch to graphics screen
  VGAScreen ();
  //Load GIF file
  LoadGIF (FileName);
  //Wait for keypress
  getch ();
  //Switch back to text mode
  TextScreen ();
}
```

Comment: I agree that this reads the file, but it does contain some information (probably useful information) about a GIF file structure which can be adapted to produce the GIF file).